# gulp-concat twice the content

Tags: javascript, gulp

That's a weird thing for me, i have a task to concat my `.js` files and then uglify them with a watcher, but the `concat` task just twice the content in every call...

Here is my gulpfile:

```
'use strict';

let gulp        = require('gulp');
let stylus      = require('gulp-stylus');
let sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
let concat      = require('gulp-concat');
let uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
let plumber     = require('gulp-plumber');
let bootstrap   = require('bootstrap-styl');
let rupture     = require('rupture');
let copy        = require('gulp-copy2');

/*
  Prepare the paths
*/
let base = './theme';
let themeName = 'own-theme';

let paths = {
  stylus    : `${base}/${themeName}/css`,
  js        : `${base}/${themeName}/js`,
  vendor    : `${base}/${themeName}/js/vendor`
}

/*
  Stylus compile
*/
gulp.task('stylus-compile', () => {
  return gulp.src([`${paths.stylus}/dev/*.styl`, `${paths.stylus}/!**/_*.styl`])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(stylus({
      use: [bootstrap(), rupture()],
      compress: true
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.stylus}`));
});

/*
  Get the bootstrap-styl js files and concat/uglify them
*/

gulp.task('bootstrap-build', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/transition.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/alert.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/button.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/carousel.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/collapse.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/dropdown.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/modal.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/tooltip.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/popover.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/scrollspy.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/tab.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/affix.js'
  ])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('bootstrap.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.vendor}`));

});

/*
  Get the js assets from NPM
*/
gulp.task('js-copy', () => {
  let dirs = [
    { src: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', dest: `${paths.vendor}/jquery.min.js` },
    { src: 'node_modules/sweet-scroll/sweet-scroll.min.js', dest: `${paths.vendor}/sweet-scroll.min.js` }
  ]
    return copy(dirs);
});

/*
  Concat/Uglify the JS files
*/
gulp.task('js-build', () => {
return gulp.src(`${paths.js}/*.js`)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('site.min.js'))
  // .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.js}`));
})

/*
  Watch
*/
gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch(`${paths.js}/*.js`, ['js-build']);
  gulp.watch(`${paths.stylus}/dev/*.styl`, ['stylus-compile']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['bootstrap-build', 'js-copy', 'watch']);
```

The `bootstrap-build` task don't twice the content no matter how many times you call the task, but the `js-build` does.

Here are the test separated scripts to concat and the results:

File 1:

```
(function() {

  console.log("oh!")
  console.log("uh!")

}).call(this);
```

File 2:

```
(function() {
  console.log("hey")
}).call(this);
```

Concated file(uh, oh file re-saved after the watcher was fired):

```
(function() {

  console.log("oh!")
  console.log("uh!")

}).call(this);
(function() {

  console.log("oh!")
  console.log("uh!")

}).call(this);
(function() {
  console.log("hey")
}).call(this);
//# sourceMappingURL=site.min.js.map

(function() {
  console.log("hey")
}).call(this);
//# sourceMappingURL=site.min.js.map
```

In every re-save, the concat twice the content... i really don't get the problem. Any idea?

Thanks in adnvance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your `bootstrap-build` works is because it places the resulting `bootstrap.min.js` in a different folder than the source files.

Your `js-build` task however concatenates all `.js` files in your `path.js` folder and places the resulting `site.min.js` in that same folder.

That means when first running `js-build` the files `file1.js` and `file2.js` are concatenated into `site.min.js`. On a second run the files `file1.js`, `file2.js` and `site.min.js` are concatenated into `site.min.js`. Every time you run your `js-build` task your `site.min.js` grows.

What you need to do is exclude `site.min.js` from being concatenated with the other files:

```
gulp.task('js-build', () => {
  return gulp.src([
      `${paths.js}/*.js`,
      `!${paths.js}/site.min.js`
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('site.min.js'))
    // .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.js}`));
})
```

Comment: In fact, that was all! ... a simple thing but i just can't see it. Thanks man, really.